# Mongodb query to get the time series record

Tags: sql, mongodb

I have the following data set

```
+---------+-------------+-----------+-----------+------+
|component|sub_component|submit_date|closed_date| state|
+---------+-------------+-----------+-----------+------+
|        A|           A1| 2019-01-13|       null|  open|
|        A|           A2| 2019-01-01| 2019-03-10|closed|
|        A|           A3| 2019-03-13| 2019-04-01|closed|
|        A|           A4| 2019-03-01| 2019-03-31|closed|
|        A|           A4| 2018-08-01| 2019-09-31|closed|
|        A|           A4| 2018-12-01| 2019-01-31|closed|
|        B|           B1| 2019-03-13|       null|  open|
|        B|           B2| 2019-03-01|       null|  open|
|        B|           B3| 2019-03-13| 2019-06-01|closed|
|        B|           B4| 2019-03-01| 2019-05-31|closed|
|        B|           B2| 2018-04-01| 2018-04-31|closed|
|        C|           c1| 2019-03-13|       null|  open|
|        C|           C2| 2019-01-15| 2019-01-26|closed|
|        C|           C3| 2019-01-26| 2019-02-01|closed|
|        C|           C4| 2019-03-01| 2019-03-31|closed|
|        C|           C5| 2019-01-01| 2019-03-31|closed|
|        C|           C8| 2017-01-01| 2017-03-31|closed|
|        D|           D1| 2019-06-13|       null|  open|
|        D|           D2| 2019-03-01|       null|  open|
|        D|           D3| 2019-03-13| 2019-06-01|closed|
+---------+-------------+-----------+-----------+------+
```

I am from a SQL background tried to write query to fetch the time series response

```
spark.sql("
select concat_ws('--', substring(submit_date, 1, 7), substring(closed_date, 1, 7)
                ) as submit_date, 
        count(*) as total_count
from data
where submit_date >= '2018-01-13' and
      submit_date <= '2019-04-31' and 
      closed_date <= '2019-04-31'
group by substring(submit_date, 1, 7), 
         substring(closed_date, 1, 7) 
order by submit_date
").show()
```

which returns the response as shown below

```
+----------------+-----------+
|     submit_date|total_count|
+----------------+-----------+
|2018-04--2018-04|          1|
|2018-12--2019-01|          1|
|2019-01--2019-01|          1|
|2019-01--2019-02|          1|
|2019-01--2019-03|          2|
|2019-03--2019-03|          2|
|2019-03--2019-04|          1|
+----------------+-----------+
```

Please help me getting the equivalent mongodb query for the same.

Comment: I have removed the MySQL tag as it has nothing to directly do with your question.

Comment: If you want an answer, you should explain the logic you want to implement.